# The word written backwards

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1)Silef is a version of the word files , written backwards.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Or should I use different sentence ? Another thing I wonder is use of “version of the word files written backwards”. Should I use apostrophe like

> 2)Silef is the word files‘s version written backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all "silef" is *not* the word "files" backwards. That would be "s**e**l**i**f".

Version 1 of your sentence is *structurally* correct but doesn't make sense. Don't use the word "version", because that implies that "selif" is some kind of acceptable variant of the word "files" - it isn't. There are no different *versions* of words, and a word written backwards is not necessarily a word ("selif" certainly isn't), so don't refer to it as such.

Also, when you are writing about a word it is best to encapsulate that word in quotation marks as I have so that it is not read as part of the sentence. For example, someone could think "*the word files*" refers to Microsoft Word computer files.

Simply say:

> "Silef" is the word "files" written backwards.

Comment: You mean my sentence is grammatically correct but is not necessary. If I use different noun instead of version would it be better?

Comment: @languagelearner Version 1 could be considered structurally correct but doesn't make sense for the reasons I gave. Also, when you are writing about a word it is best to encapsulate that word in quotation marks as I have so that it is not read as part of the sentence.